# bash "command1 || echo failed" write to the same file

Tags: bash, file, output

How can I write either the command output or "failed" to the same file? What I am trying is something like below

```
command1 || echo failed > myfile.out
```

That above command doesn't work as expected. It is always printing failed as the output to myfile.out

Comment: you may try "(command1 || echo failed) > myfile.out"

Comment: Or `{ command1 || echo failed; } > myfile.out` -- parentheses force the commands to be executed by a subshell, while curly braces just group them without forcing the subshell.

Comment: While the comment by @GordonDavisson probably solves your problem, it would be useful, if only for future readers of that question, to explain what your expectations are, and what the command actually does that does not work as expected.

Comment: @Fred So the question above is not verbose enough?

Comment: @yalkris  While experienced shell user will see right away what is wrong in this case and understand what you are expecting (and why the solution works), it is useful to describe in your question what you are trying to achieve (which you did), and what your current code actually does specifically.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments to your question probably solve your issue, but I would like to propose another way of approaching it that might be easier to understand for people not familiar with shell constructs, but with experience in other programming languages.

You could put your commands in a function, and then redirect the output of the function to the file, like this :

```
my_function()
{
  command1 || echo failed
}

my_function > myfile.out
```

The redirection would capture the whole output of the function.  This is also useful when you have many commands the output of which you want to capture together, instead of having a bunch of lines with redirections to the same file.

If you want to capture both standard out and standard error (which typically, but not necessarily, is used for status/error messages), you can do :

```
my_function > myfile.out 2>&1
```

In this line, `2>&1` means "Take the output of file descriptor 2 (stderr) and send it where file descriptor 1 (stdout) is currently going".  The order is important, as putting this redirection before the first one will not have the same result.